# Command Prompt not showing Java Version after install

Tags: java, windows, command-prompt

Noob here trying to learn java development

I installed JDK 13.0.2 in Windows 10. It install in program files\Java\jdk-13.0.2

I am unable to get the java version returned to me with "java -version"

How to get the version returned so I can write code in command prompt?

Comment: What does "unable to get" mean exactly?

Comment: command prompt does not recognize the command

Comment: Have you added the JDK to your PATH? Does `program files\Java\jdk-13.0.2` appear when you enter `echo %PATH%` into your command prompt?

Comment: You need to add java binaries in the system path. Follow instruction [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path).

Comment: No, it does not appear with echo %PATh%  Do I need to be in a specific directory?

Comment: Once the JDK's bin folder is in %PATH%, you don't need to be in any specific directory. The instructions @Quazi Irfan linked will add the bin folder to your system path.

Comment: Please edit all relevant info into the question

Comment: i edited the patch variable with "C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin" echo %PATH% does not show it. Neither does "java -version"